# How do I center text in a button?

Tags: css

Right now the clickable part is over the text and then hangs the remaining clickable area under the button. I want to center that so that I can clean up my navigation bar.

My CSS so far is

```
#mainnavi
{
    border-top:inset gold 3px;
    background-color:#000033;
    border-bottom:inset gold 3px;
    height:60px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:12px;
    width:100%;
    text-shadow:20%;
}

a:link,a:visited
{
    font-weight:bold;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#000033;
    text-align:center;
    height:30px;
    width:90px;
    text-decoration:blink;
    overflow:hidden;
}

a:hover,a:active
{
    background-color:#c0c0c0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please make a JS Fiddle and i can help you there pretty easily. Pasting your code into a comment box like that is pretty messy. Alternatively i hope this is what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/TYZX4/1/

Comment: i've only posted here a few times and anytime i post code someone edits it to fix it for me.. How do I do the above? that solution did not work :(

Comment: It seems you are missing quite of bit of your code. If you want people to help you out you need to post your HTML. You say you are using a button, yet you only provided the <a> css. More code please.

Comment: Hey! i am sorry I have had someone step in and point to where I was missing something. Thank you for responding though!!